# Modify config file during release

Tags: javascript, webpack

**Current situation**

We have many clients using our client application software. The problem is we need to connect to different REST endpoints. The base URL is always different.

Currently we're using a `config.json` file which we're manipulating during release. A simple example

**config.json**

```
{
  "endpoint": "http://localhost/api"
}
```

During startup of our application we're doing an HTTP call to get this file. For further API calls we're using the endpoint provided by the `config.json` file.

**Desired outcome**

What we really want is this becomes part of our applications instead of doing the HTTP call. We're using webpack to build our application.

In our dataservice layer we want to do something as follows:

```
import config from './config';

// use config.endpoint;
```

**config.js**

```
export default {
   endpoint: "http://localhost/api"
};
```

We can override the **confg.js** file during build. But since we have many clients (+- 30) we don't want to build for each client. We just want one build and modify the **config.js** file during release with the correct configuration.

Basically we want webpack to ignore the file during build and copy the file to the output folder + inject it in index.html.

I've done some research and I'm not sure how to solve ths issue. Maybe the initial HTTP call isn't that bad afterall?

**Edit: the endpoint is just an example, we have more client specific configuration defined in our client app**

Comment: "The base URL is always different" can you elaborate on this?
You mean, every client will have a different base url?

Comment: Yes, we currently build our app and overwrite the `config.json` file with the specific configuration needed for our client. Like endpoints and culture settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was easier than expected. I simply added a new entry with the config file.

```
entry: {
   config: "./src/config.ts",
   app: "./src/main.ts"
}
```

In the UglifyJsPlugin I added an exclude for the `config` file.

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress: {
    warnings: false
  },
  exclude: /(config).+/i,
  sourceMap: true
}),
```

The output is a "readable" config file.

Comment: How does it work? Do you have the config data for all clients in this config and the respective client queries it's config out of it?
Like `require("config")["ClientA"]`, ...etc. ?

Comment: @Legends no. We only have "dev" configuration in this file. During release with [VSO](https://www.visualstudio.com/vso/) we'll overwrite all settings in this file with the correct values for the specified client we're going to release to.

Comment: Ok, so you have a TFS build running on the server, which will manipulate the config and create releases for all clients...right?
Because I came up with different solutions, but only the one with an extra build step would have made sense...

Comment: Yes exactly, I think this will do for now! Thanks